# Force Close After Run Android Simple OCR Aplication

Tags: android, camera, ocr, tesseract

I've follow this tutorial to learn about ocr in android.
http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

After successfully run the program on my device, take a photo, it force close. As if it failed to analyze the image.

I already put the trained data on my /asset/testdata/

the trained data is downloaded from :
http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list

My logcat show that I've error on 
**java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError**

Can you teach me how to fix it?

This is the code:

```
package com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

public class SimpleAndroidOCRActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";

    // You should have the trained data file in assets folder
    // You can get them at:
    // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    protected Button _button;
    // protected ImageView _image;
    protected EditText _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };

        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path
                            + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }

        // lang.traineddata file with the app (in assets folder)
        // You can get them at:
        // http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list
        // This area needs work and optimization
        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata"))
                .exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                // GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                // while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                // gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata "
                                + e.toString());
            }
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        _field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field);
        _button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        _button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

        _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";
    }

    public class ButtonClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Camera app");
            startCameraActivity();
        }
    }

    // Simple android photo capture:
    // http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

    protected void startCameraActivity() {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            System.out.println("Bitmap Selesai");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
        //System.loadLibrary("tess");
        System.out.println("Masuk");
        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();
        System.out.println("Keluar");
        // You now have the text in recognizedText var, you can do anything with
        // it.
        // We will display a stripped out trimmed alpha-numeric version of it
        // (if lang is eng)
        // so that garbage doesn't make it to the display.

        Log.v(TAG, "OCRED TEXT: " + recognizedText);

        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
            recognizedText = recognizedText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
        }

        recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();

        if (recognizedText.length() != 0) {
            _field.setText(_field.getText().toString().length() == 0 ? recognizedText
                    : _field.getText() + " " + recognizedText);
            _field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());
        }

        // Cycle done.
    }

    // www.Gaut.am was here
    // Thanks for reading!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in your AndroidManifest.xml?:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I notice that you're trying to create files/directories during initialization, maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add `System.loadLibrary("tess");` before initializing tesseract-ocr?

Comment: You mean before TessBaseAPI? No it can't

Comment: Or like this: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/source/browse/tesseract-android-tools/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java?name=thursday_cl#40